# How to add keyboard indicator on Gnome panel?

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome-panel, applet

I am testing Fedora 19. Desktop spin gnome doesn't have a keyboard indicator. Right click doesn't work. Should it or it is information from an "ancient" gnome version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. There is no setting. The icon appears as soon as more keyboard layouts is present. [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25955/how-can-i-see-my-keyboard-layout-in-the-panel)